# regular expression to obtain forward slash before sequence of letters (ux)

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the following code:

```
df["profile"].str.replace('[x(?=/)]', '_')
```

to try to replace the **only** the "/" and *no other character*, preceding "ui" or directly following "ux", with an "_". This code is returning:

```
Multidimensional E_pressions _MDX_ Developer
```

matching only the x. My expected output is:

```
ux_ui
```

So how would I get this positive lookbehind to match "ux" and not just x?

There are other slashes in this column and so I'd like to match only the slash found with the phrase "ux/ui".

Comment: It would help if you could provide a reproducible example, some sample dataframe and expected output.

Comment: I see it all the time: Regexp newbies who think `[]` is for grouping. Where does that misunderstanding come from so much?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `[x(?=/)]` matches any single char that is either `x`, `(`, `?`, `=`, `/` or `)`. It is equal to `[x()=?/]`.

If you meant to match any `x` that is followed with `/`, you need to remove the square brackets, `x(?=/)`. However, your question sounds as *replace the only the "/" and no other character, preceding "ui" or directly following "ux", with an "_".* Then, you can use

```
 df["profile"] = df["profile"].str.replace('(?<=ux)/|/(?=ui)', '_')
```

**Details**

- `(?<=ux)/`  - `/` that is immediately preceded with `ux`
  -`|` - or
- `/(?=ui)` - `/` that is immediately followed with `ui`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iF4elc/1).

Comment: @Erin Sorry, but it is not what you asked (see *replace the "/" preceding "ui" or directly following "ux" with an "_"*). Could you please update the question? What is the rule to make `ux_ui` from `embedded linux/`?

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the confusion, I just mean that this solution is just adding an underscore regardless of the character following ux, when I only want to see an underscore when it's replacing the forward slash character "/". Does that make sense? ux_ui is part of a longer string! And the term "embedded linux engineer"  is part of this longer string and was converted to "embedded linux___ engineer" as a result of implementing "(?<=ux)" , which is why I was hoping to replace **only** the  "/" following "ux". Hope that clears things up!

Comment: @Erin **Update the *question***. The `(?<=ux)/` regex when used in `str.replace` and `_` as replacement will turn `linux/` into `linux_`. It won't add `_` in improper locations.

Comment: The reason I didn't include with the original question is because I didn't start seeing linux replaced with linux_ until I implemented your solution. My question is quite clear in that I specify that only forward slash characters "/" should be replaced. But I've gone ahead and updated for you:)

Comment: @Erin Then my answer is correct. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsuJ2a/1) showing that **only `/` is replaced with `_`**.